# How can I link (connect) two dropdowns in django admin

Tags: django, django-admin, django-admin-tools

Like: There are three dropdowns: `Country`, `Province`, and `District`.

1. Country: When I click on Country dropdown it'll display all the countries. And I'll choose one.
2. Province: When I choose a Country,
   the Province gets filtered according to country and displays all the provinces on that chose country. And I'll choose a province.
3. District: After choosing a province, the district gets filtered according to the districts inside that province.

I hope you got me. I want this to be possible in Django admin

Answer (score 0):

### Possible solution without additional libs

Using [`raw_id_fields`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.InlineModelAdmin.raw_id_fields) won't give you the select boxes as you describe but open a dialog from which it is possible to search for the district and select it. This is possible to do with the Django Admin directly and not additional libraries.

**You did not provide the code for your models and the admin, so I'm assuming a very simple model structure to illustrate the solution.**

Given these models:

```
class Country(Model):
    name = TextField(...)
    ....

class Province(Model):
    name = TextField(...)
    country = ForeignKey(..., unique=True)
    ....

class District(Model):
    name = TextField(...)
    province = ForeignKey(..., unique=True)
    ....
```

and some model that uses country:

```
class SomeLocation(Model):
    district = ForeignKey(..., unique=True)
```

**I'm assuming that this model you want an admin UI for only needs the `district` field because this uniquely defines province and country. But for the user it might be easier to select the country and province first, instead of selecting from a huge list of districts.**

Assumption: the selections of `country` and `province` are for better user experience.

If you enable the admin for `SomeLocation`:

```
from django.contrib.admin import register, ModelAdmin

@register(District):
class DistrictAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['name', 'province__name', 'province__country__name']
    list_filter = ['province', 'province__country']
    search_fields = ['name', 'province__name', 'province__country__name']

@register(SomeLocation)
class SomeLocationAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    ....
    raw_id_fields = ['district']
```

### Solution with Selects

You will have to customize the Admin by using additional libs like https://pypi.org/project/django-ajax-selects/ or write your own logic including JS. This might be more effort than is warranted for an Admin UI.